How to Export from Blender to Unreal Engine While Retaining Individual Meshes for Texturing?
I want to export an object to Unreal Engine. The only problem is that it’s actually a bunch of different meshes. When I export to Unreal, they all come through as individual meshes, which is expected. However, they don’t retain any data about their relationships to the other meshes and thus appear as random pieces. How can I export them as a single item while keeping the individual meshes accessible for texturing?
I tried using the USD export method, but I was unable to edit the UVs in Unreal with this method.
How should I go about this?

Make sure in the FBX import dialog in Unreal that Combine Meshes is checked. Otherwise it imports them as essentially the same objects they were in Blender.

I think if you add an empty object, parent the top-parent mesh objects and all non-parented mesh objects to the empty, and export the whole thing as is, it should be fine.
Before doing that, you might want to select all with A and hit ⎈ CtrlA > Apply Scale and Rotation, to be sure there are no issues.
